# How to handle gzip-compressed responses with the gsoap logging plugin; alternately, how to turn off compression completely

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib, gsoap

**UPDATE**

I have resolved the issue, at least to my satisfaction.  I was using a window size of `-15` in `inflateInit2`, based on other examples I had seen, but this was obviously not correct.  Based on a response to a similar question I changed that to `15+16` (i.e., `31`, but I'm superstitious enough to leave it as an expression) and now the gzipped content is properly decompressed and can be logged.

Yay.  I'd rather figure out how to completely disable that `Accept-Encoding` header (especially since the decompression has to be done twice now), but this works well enough for me to move on.

**ORIGINAL**

I recently had to update some WSDLs for a C++ project I'm working on, and something about the new WSDLs is causing us to specify

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

on our outgoing requests, which wasn't happening before this update. The server responds with gzip-compressed data, like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8^M
Content-Encoding: gzip^M
Vary: Accept-Encoding^M
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5^M
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET^M
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2022 15:58:32 GMT^M
Connection: close^M
Content-Length: 1979^M
^M
<gzip-compressed content>
```

This is causing problems with the logging plugin code, which apparently is upstream of the code that does the decompression for processing.  We're trying to write the compressed data as plain text to the log file, which obviously isn't working too well.

I'm trying to figure out how to do one of two things:

- Disable the `Accept-Encoding` header;
- Decompress the gzipped content in the logging plugin;

The Genivia documentation tells you how to add gzip and zlib compression to your project, but not how to disable it.  I am searching through the WSDLs and have found some data items that appear to control compression; however, none of them seem to wind up in the generated C++ code and there's nothing I can specify when building the requests to control compression.  I've been experimenting with the soap imode/omode settings, but so far nothing seems to make a difference.

I'm simultaneously trying to figure out how to use zlib calls to uncompress the compressed portion of the response, but that's not going well so far (`invalid block type` is the current error message I'm getting).

Are there any C++ programmers out there who've had to deal with gSOAP, gzip, and logging all that the same time?  If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change `logging.c` so that it would unzip the gzipped content. Then I found out that there is an easier way. Compile `stdsoap2.cpp` with `-DSOAP_DEBUG` and link it into your program. The program will then write into `SENT.log`, `RECV.log`, and `TEST.log`. In these logs, you can see all data. If it is zipped you can see it zipped and unzipped.